# can't getting html output in jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get values in select box but I am not able to get any output..
My jquery function is like this -

```
function getTrade()
{
  var tradeType = $('.tradeType').val() != '' ? $('.tradeType').val() : '';
  var partyId   = $('.partyId').val() != '' ? $('.partyId').val() : '';

  var dataString = "partyId=" +$(".partyId").val() + "&tradeType=" +$(".tradeType").val();

  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url:"getrt.php",
     data: dataString,
     success:function(data)
     {
       $('.buyRate').html(data);
     }
  });
}
```

**Here I am trying to set my output**

```
    <td>
       <select class="buyRate">
       <option>Select Rate</option>
       </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: What does `getrt.php` look like? Sidenote: those ternarys makes no sense.

Comment: @adeneo i am useing smarty that's y i have to write my php code in new file..

Comment: Ideally, your php file should return json data and returned json data should be parsed in success handler and options should be populated. But if html is returned from php file then dataType should be set to 'html'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getTrade()
{
  var tradeType = $('.tradeType').val() != '' ? $('.tradeType').val() : '';
  var partyId   = $('.partyId').val() != '' ? $('.partyId').val() : '';

  var dataString = "partyId=" +$(".partyId").val() + "&tradeType=" +$(".tradeType").val();

  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url:"getrt.php?"+dataString,
     dataType:"html",
     success:function(data){
       $('.buyRate').html(data);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Still same result @Suraj

Comment: please verify using console.log($('.partyId').val()); and console.log($('.tradeType').val()); it must show you values